# DB2 load fails with SQL3304N The table does not exist

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have created 2 tables in db2 11.5 LUW :

```
CREATE TABLE test.TABLE1(ONE INT,
TWO CHAR(10),
THREE DATE);

CREATE TABLE test.TABLE2(ONE INT,
TWO CHAR(10),
THREE DATE);
```

Both tables are selectable:

```
db2 => select * from  test.table1;

ONE         TWO        THREE
----------- ---------- ----------

  0 record(s) selected.

db2 => select * from  test.table2;

ONE         TWO        THREE
----------- ---------- ----------

  0 record(s) selected.
```

Trying to run load (even on empty tables):

```
db2 => DECLARE mycurs CURSOR FOR SELECT ONE, TWO,  THREE FROM test.table1;
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
db2 => LOAD FROM mycurs OF cursor INSERT INTO test.table2;
SQL3304N  The table does not exist.
```

Any ideas why it happens?

Comment: Your statements work for me.

Comment: Common cause: you are using different schema names or table names, or you used quotes around object names inconsistently, or default schemas were used inconsistently.

Comment: @PaulVernon Did you run it in "db2" clp? Exactly as I did?

Comment: @mao I am using same schema name (test). I do not use any quotes, as you can see in my post.

Comment: As @PaulVernon says, these statements work fine on Db2-LUW v11.5.5.0 . So you must be omitting or overlooking some detail from your environment.

Comment: Yes. I ran the exact same statements (from a clp session)

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason: it was the trailing semicolon.

This one fails - mind that the command ends with ;

```
db2 => LOAD FROM mycurs OF cursor INSERT INTO test.table2;
SQL3304N  The table does not exist.
```

But, this one works - mind that the command does not end with ;

```
db2 => LOAD FROM mycurs OF cursor INSERT INTO test.table2
SQL3501W  The table space(s) in which the table resides will not be placed in
backup pending state since forward recovery is disabled for the database.

SQL1193I  The utility is beginning to load data from the SQL statement "
select * from test.table2".
...
```

I am used to oracle syntax , where ; is expected in the end of any command. I guess this is not the case in db2.